# Change color of Back button in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, backbarbuttonitem

I am trying to change the color of the Settings button to white, but can't get it to change.

I've tried both of these:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

but no change, it still looks like this:

[image]

How do I make that button white?

Comment: It's already here, you can check the below link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64445477/14437411

Answer (score 331):

You can change the global tint color in your storyboard by clicking on an empty space on the board and select in the right toolbar "Show the file inspector", and you will see in the bottom of the toolbar the "Global Tint" option.

[image: Global Tint option in storyboard]

Comment: woah.. Nice find!. do you know how to do this programmatically?

Comment: Great find, but changing global tint to white (per the original question) will also change things like table view detail disclosure indicators to white, which would make them invisible in the table in question.

Comment: Adding on to Mike's issues: this control also makes all your text buttons this color and so you'll either have to set them to a color by hand (ie no default colors obviously) or just use a different method.

Comment: While this is a quick and easy fix, it leads to other problems if the color is white/matches the background. If you have text fields, it makes the cursor unnoticeable, which makes it look to the user as if they are not able to write on a text field because the cursor isn't visible.

Comment: This actually fixed an issue I was having with my Back Button not showing up when performing segue's within Navigation Controllers - it was because my global tint was transparent!  Thanks for this, it helped identify the issue :)

Comment: @PaulLehn To do this programmatically, in `AppDelegate.swift > application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` you can write: `self.window!.tintColor = .yourColor`

Comment: Be aware though that this is impossible to do if your view controller is only a XIB and not part of a Storyboard. In that case, you'll have @deepak's answer and set it programmatically.

Comment: Correct answer is actually down a few: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37959331/15026634

Comment: This worked, as soon as I removed the overridden code segment `self.navigationBarView.tintColor = UIColor(ciColor: Constant.DefaultThemeColor)` that has been implemented in main navigation controller

Answer (score 249):

This code changes the arrow color

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
```

If this does not work, use the code below:

```
self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

**Swift 3 Notes**

`UIColor.whiteColor()` and similar have been simplified to `UIColor.white`

Also, many previously implicit optionals have been changed to explicit, so you might need:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar =
```

Comment: `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()` worked for me (Swift 2.2)

Comment: self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()  worked for me (Swift 3)

Comment: Can you explain why to use UIBarStyle.Black?

Comment: Please update: self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor =

Comment: it only changes the arrow, back text still remains the same in Xcode 11

Answer (score 106):

Very easy to set up in the storyboard:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 69):

You should use this:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .purple
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
```

Comment: This made the button white, but made the background color much lighter.  Do you know how to give the bar's background its full color again?

Comment: This is the correct answer. It will make the bar purple, by setting the barTintColor and the title / bar buttons white.

Answer (score 49):

Swift

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
 }
```

Comment: Use in swift 3.

Comment: also tell me which swift version you can use?

Comment: And which class/file/vc in write this code in project?

Comment: At the beginning of function setCloseButton() which is called on viewWillAppear.

Comment: write in NextViewController.swift file, also write in viewDidLoad().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161185/discussion-between-deepak-tagadiya-and-jayprakash-dubey).

Comment: You can change this color via the xCode interface or how do you call it.. So select your navigation controller and at your right select the Attribute selector (4th option) then go to the 3th section where it says Large Title Text Attribute and change the color over there, this did it for me.

Answer (score 31):

### Swift 5.5

**Change complete app theme**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
     // Set for app
     UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
     return true
}
```

**Change specific controller**

```
let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: yourViewController) 
navController.navigationBar.tintColor = .red

present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: it changes the color for all the application. What if I need to change it for particular screen/particular `UINavigationController`?

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov above answer is for complete app theme, if you want to change specific controller.

Do something like this: 

let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: yourViewController)
navController.navigationBar.tintColor = .red

Comment: If you are on iOS 13 you don't use didFinishLaunchingWithOptions anymore, it was moved to SceneDelegate.

Answer (score 21):

You can use like this one. Place it inside `AppDelegate.swift`.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(rgba: "#2c8eb5")
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 15):

In **Swift3**, To set the Back button to `red`.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: this will set the navigation bar, not the bar button item

Comment: Yep, that was the question.

Comment: "Change color of Back **button** in navigation bar"

Comment: This was the only method that worked for me. Something seems broken with Apple's implementation right now...

Answer (score 14):

In Swift 4, you can take care of this issue using:

```
let navStyles = UINavigationBar.appearance()
// This will set the color of the text for the back buttons.
navStyles.tintColor = .white
// This will set the background color for navBar
navStyles.barTintColor = .black
```

Answer (score 14):

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black // to change the all text color in navigation bar or navigation 
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white // change the navigation background color
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.black] // To change only navigation bar title text color
```

Comment: Works with Swift 5

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3**

The most upvoted answer is not correct for Swift 3.

[image]

The correct code to change color is:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

If you want to change color, change UIColor.white above to the desired color

Comment: This was the only method that worked for me. Something seems broken with Apple's implementation right now...

Answer (score 9):

All the answers setting `UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor` conflict with Apple's documentation in `UIAppearance.h`.

> Note for iOS7: On iOS7 the `tintColor` property has moved to `UIView`, and now has special inherited behavior described in `UIView.h`.
>   This inherited behavior can conflict with the appearance proxy, and therefore `tintColor` is now disallowed with the appearance proxy.

In Xcode, you need to command-click on each property you want to use with appearance proxy to inspect the header file and make sure the property is annotated with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`.

So the correct way to color the navigation bar purple and the title and buttons white throughout the app via the appearance proxy is:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .purple
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = .white
```

Note that `UIBarButtonItem` is not a subclass of `UIView` but rather `NSObject`. So its `tintColor` property is not the inherited `tintColor` from `UIView`.

Unfortunately, `UIBarButtonItem.tintColor` is not annotated with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` – but that seems to me a documentation bug. The response from Apple Engineering in [this radar](http://www.openradar.me/34303797) states it is supported.

Comment: UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white] //also

Answer (score 9):

If you tried many times but could not work, you may try :

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).tintColor = .red
```

Actually, I tried many times, only found this way will work.

Comment: You are a life savor, no other solution worked for me, thanks mate

Comment: Important to note that this code goes in the VC that is PREVIOUS to the one you are trying to change, not in the one you're trying to change.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!!

Comment: Worked like a charm, It worked for all view controller.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 5 Updated**

If you need to set `Back` button color globally, you could simply use:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = Asset.pureWhite.color
```

Then you do not need to set back button background color on each view controller. If you use this one you **COULD NOT SET BACK BUTTON COLOR ON ANOTHER VIEW CONTROLLER**

**BUT**

If you need to set Back button color on view controller or change on another view controller do not use above method. You could use:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.font:FontFamily.BatonTurbo.medium.font(size: 20),
                                  .foregroundColor: Asset.pureWhite.color] // Naviagtion Title attributes
appearance.backgroundColor = .red // Navigation bar background color

self.navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
self.navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
self.navigationItem.compactAppearance = appearance

navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .green // Back button color
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this code in `AppDelegate` class, inside of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white

}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

This snippet does the magic. Instead of the redColor, change it to as your wish.

Answer (score 4):

Lets try this code:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()  // Back buttons and such
    navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()  // Bar's background color
    navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]  // Title's text color

    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir

Answer (score 4):

in swift 2.0 use

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why nobody has mentioned this...but I was doing exactly what you were doing in my **`viewDidLoad`**...and it wasn't working. Then I placed my code into **`viewWillAppear`** and it all worked.

The above solution is to change a *single* barbuttonItem. If you want to change the color for *every* navigationBar in your code then  follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30018136/5175709).

Basically changing onto the class itself using `appearance()` is like making a global change on all instances of that view in your app. For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324310/customizing-appearance-of-uisearchbar-uinavigationbar-in-appdelegate-why-cust)

Answer (score 4):

If you already have the back button in your "Settings" view controller and you want to change the back button color on the "Payment Information" view controller to something else, you can do it inside "Settings" view controller's prepare for segue like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { 
    if segue.identifier == "YourPaymentInformationSegue"
    {
        //Make the back button for "Payment Information" gray:
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.gray               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add following code to **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function in **AppDelegate.swift**

```
var navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()

navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = uicolorFromHex(0xffffff) // White color
navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = uicolorFromHex(0x034517) // Green shade

// change navigation item title color
navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes =[NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Comment: This code gives me the following error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'uicolorFromHex'"  Can anyone help me solve that?

Comment: probably an extension for UIColor. You can search stackoverflow how to create an extension.

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 2.0, To change the **Navigation-bar tint color**, **title text** and **back button** tint color changed by using the following in AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

  // Override point for customization after application launch.


    //Navigation bar tint color change

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 42/255.0, green: 140/255.0, blue: 166/255.0, alpha: 0.5)

    //Back button tint color change

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor =  UIColor(red: 204/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 204/255.0, alpha: 1)

    //Navigation Menu font tint color change

    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 204/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 204/255.0, alpha: 1), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Bold", size: 25)!]//UIColor(red: 42/255.0, green: 140/255.0, blue: 166/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent


    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have one choice hide your back button and make it with your self.
Then set its color.

I did that:

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
let backbtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style:UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "backTapped:")
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backbtn
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
```

Comment: The question was specifically around styling the left navigation item and this is the closest to answering the question directly.

Answer (score 2):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

This works for me, iOS 9.0+

Answer (score 2):

For some reason it isn't working for me programmatically.  However setting it in the storyboard works every time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I prefer custom NavigationController rather than setting global ui, or put in ViewController.

Here is my solution

```swift
class AppNavigationController : UINavigationController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = self
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

  }

}
extension AppNavigationController : UINavigationControllerDelegate {

  func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    let backButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
      title: "   ",
      style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain,
      target: nil,
      action: nil)
    backButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.gray
    viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButtonItem
  }

  func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

  }

}
```

Also you don't need to mess with Apple Api like **EKEventEditViewController**,**PickerViewController** and so on if you use global settings ui like `UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = .white`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this in swift 5 and worked for me

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor(named: "uberRed")
```

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI, do the following:

Define a BackButton struct:

```
struct BackButton: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Text("Back")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the second view, use it as follows:

```
struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Second View")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Second View", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                BackButton()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution does work, but it's worth noting that using `navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` also disables the functionality of swiping to go back to the previous view.

Answer (score 0):

It will be solved with this line in -(void)viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
```

Comment: `(lldb) p self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem
(UIBarButtonItem *) $9 = nil
(lldb) `

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .black
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.3:**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "custom-back-image")
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "custom-back-image")
```