# How to change back button color in nav bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Is there a way to change only the left side back button color in an app with a navigation controller?

There are plenty of examples changing colors in the navbar but those all affect the navbar title as well. I don't want to change the title. Just the back button (text + chevron) color.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color of Back button in navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733936/change-color-of-back-button-in-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use Below To Change Back Button Color:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

To Change Title Color of The Navigation Bar Use:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
```

Comment: Does nothing to the back button.

Comment: It should work. May be put "?" sign with the navigationController might help.

Comment: Your top code worked. After Cleans and Rebuilds, it finally worked. None of the other answers had any effect.

Comment: Unfortunately on iPhone, after switch to landscape and back to portrait, the tintColor is somehow reset.

Answer (score 1):

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
```

**Since iOS 7.0 UITextAttributeTextColor was replaced by NSForegroundColorAttributeName**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [UITextAttributeTextColor: UIColor.blueColor()]
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor();
```

Comment: Doesn't change the back button color.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = UIColor.blue
}
```