# How to change the color of a NavigationBar?

Tags: ios, colors

I am trying to change the color of the text "Welcome" in the Navigation Bar.
As you see now it is blue and I want to change it to white as the rest of the text in the Navigation Bar.

Would you give me any ideas? I tried to add some code and it is working, because the clock was black and now is white, like it should be, but the "Welcome" is still staying in blue.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color of Back button in navigation bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733936/change-color-of-back-button-in-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in either your app delegate in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, or in your navigationController's custom class

```
let customColor = UIColor.redColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:customColor]
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = customColor
```