# Customizing appearance of UISearchBar & UINavigationBar in AppDelegate? Why customize at class and not instance level?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started). In its AppDelegate it has a `customizeAppearance()` where `UISearchBar` & `UINavigationBar` are type/class properties. Shouldn't they be a property of something like the window or the current viewController we are in?! How can we just message a class and then have it change our UI?

FWIW when I cmmd click...obviously it just takes it to the class definition.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var backgroundSessionCompletionHandler: (() -> Void)?
  var window: UIWindow?
  let tintColor =  UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 71/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)

  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    customizeAppearance()
    return true
  }

  func application(application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = completionHandler
  }

  // MARK - App Theme Customization

  private func customizeAppearance() {
    window?.tintColor = tintColor
    UISearchBar.appearance().barTintColor = tintColor // shouldn't UISearchBar be a property of some other object?
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = tintColor // shouldn't UINavigationBar be a property of some other object?
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
  }
}
```

Comment: Quoting [the language reference for `UISearchBar`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchbar): _"You can customize the appearance of search bars one at a time, or you can use the appearance proxy (`[UISearchBar appearance]`) to customize the appearance of all search bars in an app."_. In the tutorial you follow, they've chosen the latter proxy approach, making use of the static `appearance()` method of as blueprinted in [the `UIAppearance` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiappearance) to which e.g. `UISearchBar` conforms to (via `UIView` inheritance).

Comment: @dfri ohh. wow. That's convenient. So if I change one at a time and also customize using appearance. The proxy method would be override right? Also Is this *proxy* mechanism offered elsewhere in Cocoa touch or no?

Comment: I can't really say without testing, but further quoting the language ref. for `UIAppearance`: _"iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window ..."_ as well as _"In any given view hierarchy, the outermost appearance proxy wins."_. So I believe depending on where (or at what depth) you choose to customize your appearance, the default /customized proxy behaviour (loads upon view entering window) _or_ your custom instance-set behaviour will take precedence. Have a look at the ref. docs for `UIAppearance` for det.s.

Comment: @dfri Thank you so much. 2 more questions :D. 1) The best place to load such is within `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ie use it as a entry point for customization. Right? 2) there is no UISearchBar created here. Only that any searchBar loaded in the coming up classes would be affected by such customization. right?

Comment: 1. I can't really say, but based on the tutorial, they've chosen that point, so I believe the RayWenderlichauthor would say _"yes"_ :) 2. Yes, that's also how I interpret it: the `UISearchBar` customization is set for the proxy of `UISearchBar`, and will then be applied _for all instance_ of `UISearchBar` (in the project, I believe?). I becomes tricky, however, if you start defining your custom conformance to [`UIAppearanceContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiappearancecontainer), e.g. for some custom `UISearchBar` of yours. In that case, I can't really speculate over ...

Comment: ... what takes precedence, but in performing this tutorial of yours, it would be an excellent point to test these things out :) and if you have any insights that are not entirely clear from the docs, I would encourage you to add them as an answer to your own question. Addendum: [the following blog post](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/) is somewhat outdated, but instructive nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I'll add my comments—answering the OP's question regarding class level customization—as an answer, as comments are not persistent. Possibly the OP himself/herself can add an alternative thorough answer based on trying out the queries discussed in the comments)*

---

Quoting [the language reference for `UISearchBar`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchbar):

> **Customizing Appearance**
>
> You can customize the appearance of search bars one at a time, or you
>   can use **the appearance proxy** (`[UISearchBar appearance]`) to customize
>   the appearance of all search bars in an app.

The appearance proxy is covered e.g. in the [UIKit User Interface Catalog - About Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/index.html):

> **Appearance Proxies**
>
> You can use an appearance proxy **to set particular appearance
>   properties for all instances of a view in your application**. For
>   example, if you want all sliders in your app to have a particular
>   minimum track tint color, you can specify this with a single message
>   to the slider’s appearance proxy.
>
> There are two ways to customize appearance for objects: for all
>   instances and for instances contained within an instance of a
>   container class.
>
> ...

As well as in the language reference for the [`UIAppearance` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiappearance)

> Use the `UIAppearance` protocol to get the appearance proxy for a
>   class. You can customize the appearance of instances of a class by
>   sending appearance modification messages to the class’s appearance
>   proxy.
>
> ...
>
> - To customize the appearance of all instances of a class, **use `appearance()` to get the appearance proxy for the class**.

In the tutorial you follow, they've chosen to use of the appearance proxy approach, making use of the static `appearance()` method as blueprinted in the `UIAppearance` protocol (to which e.g. `UISearchBar` conforms to, via `UIView` inheritance) to get and modify the appearance proxy of all `UISearchBar` (and `UINavigationBar`) instances, from a class level.

---

The following blog post covers the subject of the appearance proxy. An instructive read, even though being slightly outdated and using Obj-C rather than Swift:

- [NSHipster - UIAppearance](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/)