# How to change the default Navigate-Back button color in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there anyway to change the default Navigate-Back button color?
I am using SwiftUI with NavigationView

[image]

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733936/change-color-of-back-button-in-navigation-bar answer your question?

Comment: @luckystars SwiftUI does not involve the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `accentColor` property on the `NavigationView` to set the back button color.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Show Detail View")
                }.navigationBarTitle("Navigation")
            }
        }.accentColor(.red) // Replace it with required color.
    }
}
```

**AccentColor view modifier Sets the accent color for this view and the views it contains.**

Comment: @John For further customisation, checkout this SO answer :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571349/custom-back-button-for-navigationviews-navigation-bar-in-swiftui

Answer (score 0):

[`NavigationView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview) has two view modifiers that will probably meet your needs: [`foregroundColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview/foregroundcolor(_:)) and [`accentColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview/accentcolor(_:)).